# SQL Pass 2013 Session recordings

Tags: sql-server

I am going through the below link and am really interested in watching Paul White's

Understanding the Optimizer and Interpreting Execution Plans

http://www.pass.org/summit/2013/Sessions/Schedule.aspx

But I couldn't find this session anywhere in the pass learning/recording session.

Can someone let me know how I can get this?

Answer (score 9):

That was a full day pre-conference session, for which a fee (separate from the main conference) was required to attend. It was not recorded, and so will never be available.

From the [PASS Summit 2013 FAQs](http://www.pass.org/summit/2013/About/FAQs.aspx): (emphasis added)

> **What will be included on the PASS Summit 2013 session recordings and how can I purchase them?**
>
> The PASS Summit 2013 session recordings include all the Conference Sessions, including half-day sessions and spotlights. **(Note: Pre-Conference Sessions are not recorded.)** Attendees can purchase either the session recordings download option for $195 or the recordings on USB flash drive for $240 (one session recordings purchase at the attendee price per attendee). Note: Shipping charges for the USB flash drive are $20 within the continental US and $30 international. Streaming of the sessions will be made available for free to attendees after Summit.

Answer (score 1):

It might be best to email PASS directly http://www.pass.org/AboutPASS/Contact.aspx

My unofficial observation is that a lot of the longer sessions (especially the half day / day ones) are either not recorded or never posted. It's a real bummer.